# Is the Doctor's tomb in 'The Name of the Doctor' still yet to happen?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

I mean will we see the Doctor fill that tomb someday or has it already happened and time has been rewritten from some time?

Comment: Good question! I assumed that history was rewritten and that tomb isn't going to happen after all, but who knows with this show ...

Comment: But time couldn't have been rewritten around that time because nothing was to be rewritten since the Doctor got his regeneration in the time of the Doctor. So I'm assuming it's later on, what do you think?

Comment: I mean, when would the Doctor have died that you are saying is rewritten ?

Comment: My interpretation was that the Time Lords giving him extra regenerations at Trenzalore was in a way a rewriting of history. But if that hasn't been said explicitly on the show, I guess they could take it in any direction.

Comment: @DominicWilson: “time couldn't have been rewritten” — when discussing Doctor Who, I don’t think that phrase is ever likely to be true.

Comment: Ok thanks, but if in the original timeline the time lords didn't give the regenerations to him and 11 died. How could capaldi come to save gallifrey since gallifrey was always to be saved but the war Doctor and 10 forgot about it

Answer (score 6):

There's no good answer really. Heck, [even Steven Moffat doesn't have a good answer](http://www.blastr.com/2014-4-3/moffat-explains-why-doctor-didnt-die-trenzalore-little-help-doctor-himself) (this is supposedly The Doctor talking)

> Changing time is tricky. It’s a bit like a detective story: so as long there isn’t an actual body, you’ve got a certain amount of wiggle room – for instance, if the body has, rather conveniently, been burned on a boat in Utah. Here’s the thing: I can change the future so long as the future has not already been established as part of my own past. I can’t rescue Amy and Rory because I already know that I didn’t.
>
> But what do I know about Trenzalore? There’s a big monument that looks very like my TARDIS. There’s a temporal fissure leading to my timeline. Maybe it’s my grave. Maybe, one day, it’s my burial ground. Maybe it is something else entirely, and we got it all wrong. Don’t know. Don’t plan to find out for as long as possible. The main thing is, Clara still jumped into my time stream, and ended up helping me through all of my life. All that is established, unchanged – but there’s wiggle room!

So there you have it. Because <s>reasons</s> <s>timey wimey</s> Steven Moffat

There's some problems making it a future grave (why didn't we see #12 in the scene with the Doctors running around Clara?) but nothing that can't be waved away. And if I were going to die, I'd pick the spot where everyone says I was supposed to die.

Comment: I have always thought of those "fixed points in time" as the Doctor's kryptonite. You have to limit him somehow.

Comment: I tend to agree. But Moffat, above, seems to be transmuting that from "fixed point in time" to "anything that has actually happened in the series"

Answer (score 5):

The way I see it, it is a future that probably won't happen anymore, like the twelfth Doctor explained in the episode *In The Forest of the Night*

> CLARA: But we saw the future. Lots of futures. Earth's futures.
>
> DOCTOR: They're about to be erased.

This implies that futures that are not fixed points in time, can be rewritten.

Originally, the Doctor's last incarnation (Matt Smith's Eleventh Doctor, who was actually the thirteenth and final) was supposed to die in Trenzalore, defending the town of Christmas. Thanks to Clara's intervention, the Timelords granted the Doctor a new Regeneration cycle, so the future we saw in *The Name of the Doctor* never actually happened.

(Which causes kind of a paradox, because if it didn't happen, then Clara didn't become the impossible girl, so she couldn't travel with the Doctor at all, so she couldn't convince the Timelords to help the Doctor, which would have caused his death in Trenzalore after all, so....my head hurts).

Comment: +1 because I agree with this ... BUT ... didn't he say something before about how it *was* a fixed point in time? Since he'd seen it himself it couldn't be changed, or something?

Comment: fixed points can sometimes be changed

Comment: and she could travel with the doctor since the version she met in modern time, not Victorian or in the asylum. He COULD have met her anyway without her being the impossible girl because she's the origin of it

Comment: @Randal'Thor You're probably thinking about his death in Lake Silencio, which did become a fixed point in time. His death in Trenzalore wasn't mentioned as such.

Comment: What then is a fixed point if it can be changed? It also begs the question, why was Time's first draft wrong?

Comment: @tilley31 Ah. I'm not actually familiar with the Smith series yet.

Comment: @JDoe You're trying to make logical sense out of Doctor Who ... this isn't going to end well.

Comment: the time lords decided to help the doctor and give him a regeneration because if he were to die then capaldi could have never helped save gallifrey and that's why they saved him

Comment: ... wibbly, wobbly, timey, wimey ...

Comment: Doctor Who seems to get around the possibility of paradoxes (except when they're the point of the story) by having a sort of meta-time perpendicular to normal time. Consider, for instance, that despite the "Time War" being fought, by definition, all over time, it can still be "over." Similarly, other than quick gags such as 10 meeting Rose again before dying and River and Clara's 'special' timelines, most major characters seem to meet the Doctor "in order" - the Master is a good example of this.

Comment: @Amadeus9 just like Amy Pond's parents. They were erased from time, but she still existed.